# Is there a way to hook up to the TypeScript compiler and emit some custom JavaScript code based on the TypeScript code model?

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if I can somehow extend or hook up to the TypeScript compiler and generate some functions based on the declaration of the TypeScript interfaces in my code. Basically these functions would validate the data objects that are coming from the server to comply with the TypeScript interfaces the objects are supposed to implement. I was thinking to have a special interface-marker and I wish my hook to the compiler was triggered by such interface. Once that marker-interface is detected I would analyze the members of that interface and generate the code that would validate a given object against the data-contract defined by that interface. Is there a way to do that? Can anyone give some directions[?](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/502864)

Comment: If you want data validation, it probably should sit in your program instead of the compiler.  If you can't get access to TypeScript interfaces, it might be better to create concrete objects that implement those interfaces (which the compiler will type-check), and then use those objects to validate your data.  A single validation function can validate any data object against any interface object.

Comment: how can you utilize the typescript interfaces and compiler'r type ckeck for json that comes to you at runtime via ajax?

Comment: First create an interface.  Then create an object implementing that interface.  That object will obviously have all the properties required by that interface (and hopefully not any more).  Then deserialize the JSON into an object. Then write a validation function that takes this interface object, enumerate its properties, and then verify whether the object contains all of these properties and are of the correct types.  Then enumerate the object's properties and verify that it doesn't contain anything more.

Comment: hm, that's an interesting idea

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer**

Yes (thanks to TypeScript transformers), and there already exists a tool like that called [typescript-is](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is).

**Long answer**

A *transformer* is a function for which the AST of your program is exposed. A basic example:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';

export default (program: ts.Program) => {
    return (ctx: ts.TransformationContext) => {
        return (sourceFile: ts.SourceFile) => {
            function visitor(node: ts.Node): ts.Node {
                /**
                 * If that's the kind of node you were looking for,
                 * do something with it and return it. Otherwise:
                 */
                return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, ctx);
            }

            return ts.visitEachChild(sourceFile, visitor, ctx);
        };
    };
}
```

Such a transformer can be used programmatically. If you would rather make it a standalone plugin used in your `tsconfig.json`, you will need a wrapper for the TypeScript compiler that supports that, because TypeScript [doesn't support plugins out of the box](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14419) yet. [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript) is an example of such a wrapper.

Comment: Cool tool, was about to post some code that extracted type info from interfaces but this is totally better :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an interesting idea.  I think you'd probably end up needing to modify the compiler code to do this; standard "tsc" doesn't export type information, other than the --declaration command line option, which I don't think does what you want.

You might start by looking at some code that has done a programmatic integration with the TS compiler.  For instance, the grunt type script module:
https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript/blob/master/src/modules/compiler.ts

Still, this seems like a non-trivial problem.  One way is to create TS code that references one of your data objects and tries to compile it to see if that data conforms to an interface.  If you end up having to use the compiler itself to do this validation, you would probably find that its too slow for real time use.

Or, if you generate code yourself based on your marker interfaces, you might end up reimplementing a lot of the compiler, since the type system can get pretty complex (generics, function declarations, and structural subobjects come to mind)